# How can I disable root ng-click button in div?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

My code:

```
<div ng-click="someAction()">
    <button ng-click="otherAction()"></button>
</div>
```

Click on Button should only call otherAction() without calling someAction(). Click rest of div should call someAction().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `$event.stopPropagation()` to stop propagation from the inner scope to the outer scope:

```
<div ng-click="someAction()">
    <button ng-click="otherAction(); $event.stopPropagation();"></button>
</div>
```

or

```
<div ng-click="someAction()">
    <button ng-click="otherAction($event)"></button>
</div>
```

modifying the `otherAction` code as follow:

```
$scope.otherAction = function($event) {
    $event.stopPropagation();
    // Existing code
}
```

Comment: I think the former of the two options should be preferred.  The code explaining how `someAction` won't be called in kept in a related place if the latter is used.  

Putting `$event.stopPropagation` in the controller essentially hides in a different file the reason why `someAction` isn't called.

Comment: Yes it depends if this is a specific function used only on that button or not. But yes, generally the first is better, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

pass the event on the button ng-click

```
<button ng-click="otherAction($event)"></button>
```

and the on the otherAction function you just stopPorpagation or preventDefault

```
$scope.otherAction = function($event){ $event.stopPropagation; };
```